# postgresqlの初期化失敗 (homebrew使用)

Tags: macos, postgresql

homebrewを利用してインストールしたpostgresqlの初期化が失敗してしまいます。

状況
macbook airからproへ買い替えデータの移行を実施
railsでサーバアクセス時に下記エラーが発生

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
```

一度、postgresql(9.4.4)をhomebrewからアンインストールして再度インストール。
`initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`を実施するも下記エラーが発生

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "Kuma".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "ja_JP.UTF-8".
initdb: could not find suitable text search configuration for locale "ja_JP.UTF-8"
The default text search configuration will be set to "simple".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgres".
```

[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700596/homebrew-postgres-broken)を参考にJamesさんの回答通り下記コマンドを実行。
`rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`
さらに`mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres`を実施するも
`mkdir: /usr/local/var/postgres: File exists`とフォルダがかってに作成されておりうまくいきません。
どなたか本件の解決方法知らないでしょうか？

Comment: 勝手に作成された `/usr/local/var/postgres` ディレクトリの中にはどの様なファイルがありますか？ それとも空ディレクトリでしょうか？

Comment: server.logファイルと.(ディレクトリ)と..(ディレクトリ)があります。

Comment: もしかして postgresql のサーバプロセスが実行中なのではないでしょうか？ それらを全てシャットダウンしてから削除を行う方が良いかと思います。